# Get the QUERY PLAN without executing the query?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to optimize a long-running query in PostgreSQL 11.

Every time I tweak the query or create some new indexes and then do an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ...` to see if it worked, I have to wait a long time for the explanation.

Is there a way to get the QUERY PLAN without actually executing the query, dare I say it, *just like the way it works in MySQL*?

Comment: Just do `EXPLAIN` without the `ANALYZE`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) just run it without `analyze`

> The `ANALYZE` option causes the statement to be actually executed, not only planned

```
explain
select ...
from ...
where ...
```

or

```
explain
update ...
```